# Facebook linking to website -- need default thumbnail

Tags: facebook

**SOLUTION: [Facebook Lint Service - refreshing page cache](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint)**

Hey --

NOTE:: Using .NET and IIS

I've looked at plenty of guides to do this, but I cannot get any thumbnails, titles, descriptions to show up.

Here's my problem -- it works when i have: www.sitename.com/default.aspx
But I need simply: www.sitename.com

Any idea how this is done? In my server control panel I have default.aspx to be the page to bring up when there's no specified page for the directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mod Rewrite, to accept / and rewrite to default.aspx.
check out http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html

Comment: ahh, ok, what you are describing sounds odd. Do you have a base href set to default.aspx?

Comment: Yes, in my IIS configurations the first ranked default page is default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a 301 redirect in your .htaccess file.

http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml

Comment: Actually -- I'm using .NET on IIS, which uses web.config. I'm thinking .htaccess is the web.config for IIS?